# HtmlElement framework: is it possible to use dynamic locators

Tags: dynamic, findby, htmlelements

I use Html Elements framework and where is need to use following xpath:

```
.//div/div[text()='" + id+ "']/a
```

But @FindBy annotation doesn't support dynamic locators. Is where any way to use them in Html Elements framework?

Another example:

There is table with list of some entities. Table has 3 columns: name of entity, second and delete button. The test is to delete specific entity. So I need to press "Delete" button which corresponds given entity. I do this using locator:

```
.//div/table/tbody/tr/td[text()='" + id + "']/following-sibling::td[3]/div
```

Html structure is like:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td >
     <a>text1</a>
  </td>
  <td</td>
  <td>
     <div>delete<div/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td >
     <a>text2</a>
  </td>
  <td</td>
  <td>
     <div>delete<div/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Entity to delete would change every time, so I could find it only by text(name).
So how do this using Page Factory?

Comment: Generally, using dynamic locators is a bad idea, it makes your tests fragile. A lot of people asked about this feature, but we always find a way to solve their problem without dynamic locators. So, can you explain please in more details what problem you solving?

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: First of all, you can use `Table` element from HtmlElements to simplify working with tables. Second, write some code which will iterate over table rows finding required one. It will work the same way your dynamic locator would, but more clear.

Comment: Another good approach to simplify your tests is playing with test data. For example, you can clear all data from table before your test, so you'll have only one row and no need to search required one.

Comment: It is impossible to clear all data as where are many users who need that data. The first one would be great, but using Table I could get only td element and text is in td/a, so I don't know how get child of particular table cell